# Histogram with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I have a fairly large dataframe, with shape of `559x14`, which was created from a dictionary. The dictionary had keys with non-uniform list lengths and I have assembled the dataframe as follows:

```
data_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
data_df = data_df.transpose()
```

When I try to plot a histogram by filtering out certain elements, I run into problems. The way I am filtering is as follows:

```
is_tru = data_df.profiles == 'profile_name'
temp_df = data_df[is_tru]
```

When I try to plot histogram for a certain column name

```
plt.figure()
plt.hist(temp_df.inc, bins=50, density = True)
plt.show()
```

I get the following chart

[image]

Whereas, when I plot it using the following code snippet

```
plt.figure()
# Essentially unpacking into a list
plt.hist([ii for ii in temp_df.inc], bins=50, density = True)
plt.show()
```

I get the desired chart which looks like this

[image]

Although I'm getting the desired plot, I'd like to know what is going wrong in method 1. I could not come up appropriate keywords for the search, hence had to create this question. Any leads in this matter will be appreciated.

Thank you.

P.S : Method 1 worked when I had a dictionary with uniform list lengths and did not have to do the transpose. The dataset changed and I had to use this method to create the dataframe. I am suspecting that the problem lies in the way I am creating the dataframe.

Comment: As all values in the first histogram are equal and 14, which is also the column count in the initial dataframe, this gives me an impression that transposing the dataframe is playing a role. Why do you need to tanspose.

Comment: May be if you simply `print (temp_df.inc)` and `print ([ii for ii in temp_df.inc])`, you will get your answer

Comment: @PankajJoshi I am transposing because it makes life easy for filtering..There could be a way to filter using the row names, but I'm new to pandas and am unaware of any such methods.

Comment: @Bazingaa The output in both cases is same, without any differences.